Algolia search just hangs when ran the 2nd time?
...
@override
  Future<List<String>> searchPosts({
    required String author,
    required String title,
    required String content,
  }) async {
      _postsSearcher.applyState(
        (state) => state.copyWith(
          query: content,
          page: 0,
          hitsPerPage: 1,
          facetFilters: [
            'author:$author',
            'title:$title',
          ],
        ),
      );

      final results = await _searchPage.first;
      final postIds = results.items.map((post) => post.postId).toList();

      return postIds;
  }
}

class HitsPage {
  const HitsPage(this.items, this.pageKey, this.nextPageKey);

  factory HitsPage.fromResponse(SearchResponse response) {
    final items = response.hits.map(PostModel.fromJson).toList();
    final isLastPage = response.page >= response.nbPages;
    final nextPageKey = isLastPage ? null : response.page + 1;
    return HitsPage(items, response.page, nextPageKey);
  }

  final List<PostModel> items;
  final int pageKey;
  final int? nextPageKey;
}

I'm developing in Flutter and made a button that calls:Future<List<String>> searchPosts. (Clean Architecture setup)
It works fine the first time but when I click the button the second time, the app is stuck at
final results = await _searchPage.first;

Any ideas?
I reckon it has something to do with Stream but not sure. Also, why does it just hang?

Have you closed the stream after you get the search results?

you have not provide the full code, so it is hard to say where does the problem come from. however, the issue you're facing, most likely, comes from how you are handling the stream. To make sure the stream properly emits new events for each search query and updates correctly, your code should look something like this:
class SearchStream {
  final StreamController<HitsPage> _searchResultsController = StreamController<HitsPage>();
  Stream<HitsPage> get searchResultsStream => _searchResultsController.stream;

  // here in dispose function you need to call close() on your stream
  void dispose() {
    _searchResultsController.close();
  }
  Future<List<String>> searchPosts({
    required String author,
    required String title,
    required String content,
  }) async {
    final mockResponse = SearchResponse(
      hits: [
        {'postId': '1', 'title': 'Post 1'},
        {'postId': '2', 'title': 'Post 2'},
      ],
      page: 0,
      nbPages: 1,
    );

    final results = HitsPage.fromResponse(mockResponse);
    final postIds = results.items.map((post) => post.postId).toList();

    _searchResultsController.add(results);

    return postIds;
  }
}

